# How can I look up the 2 axis values by inputting a number?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet, lookup

I'm a graphic designer and not very familiar with Excel but I'm fairly sure it's the simplest solution to my problem. I have a table (see below) with 2 axis going from A to L. Inside that table are a set of numbers. I want to be able to look up the 2 axis values by inputting a number.

For example: If I used the value '14' it would return E and B. It would be great if I could have a column of these figures to look up then a column next to it with one axis value and another column with the other axis value.

I'm aware this is a big question with probably a fair few steps but I'm a bit stumped and not really sure where to start. I'm not looking for an answer spelt out to me but if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

So far I've tried using `=CHAR(ROW("RN")+64)` and `=CHAR(COLUMN("CL")+64)` where RN is row number and CN is column letter. While this works, I cannot link all the values in the table unless I do them one by one.

How can I look up the 2 axis values by inputting a number?

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L
A       1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11
B           12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21
C               22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
D                   31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38
E                       39  40  41  42  43  44  45
F                           46  47  48  49  50  51
G                               52  53  54  55  56
H                                   57  58  59  60
I                                       61  62  63
J                                           64  65
K                                               66
L
```

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: 'I want to be able to look up the 2 axis values by inputing a number.'

Comment: That is a statement, but I updated your question to fit the format of this Q&A site. What version of Excel are you using? It may be relevant to the answer(s) given.

Comment: 2015 (15.11.2) on Mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is in A1:M13, this formula uses a value input into cell O2 and returns the column and row header corresponding to that value. For example, if you input `63`, the formula returns `LI`.

```
=INDEX(A1:M1,SUM(IF(A1:M13=O2,COLUMN(A1:M13),"")))&INDEX(A1:A13,SUM(IF(A1:M13=O2,ROW(A1:M13),"")))
```

This is an array formula, and must be confirmed with ctrl+shift+enter.

Edit: Here's a version that works without being array-entered:

```
=INDEX(A1:M1,SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:M13=O2)*COLUMN(B2:M13)))&INDEX(A1:A13,SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:M13=O2)*ROW(B2:M13)))
```